# Rewrite condition for redirecting traffic to Google

Tags: .htaccess, magento, brute-force

I am trying to block access to Magento rss feed with the following rule in my htaccess file:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/CATALOG [OR,NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/RSS/ORDER [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

The problem is that all traffic is redirected to my site anyway and this causes server overload. How can I redirect traffic to Google with 403? Or is there another way?

Comment: Very  simple. Just use the Google url as The Rule's destination   `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://Google.com/ [R=302,L]`

Comment: My hosting added this, but I do not trust them so not sure whether this is going to make a difference:                                     
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*rss [OR,NC]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^rss/order [NC]
     RewriteRule .* - [F]